# Overwrite a specific memory address in android

Tags: android

So im wondering if it is possible to overwrite a specific address several times, kind of like formatting so that nothing can be recovered from that location. As in a multiple pass wipe, where the first pass all 1's are written and then a second with all 0's. But only where a specific file is/was.

Comment: its java, so yes. pass by reference

Comment: On disk?  There's no low level access like that, although if you have a rooted phone you could install a linux utility to do it.  Be careful of doing it often though-  flash has a limited number of write cycles, writing to the same location repeatedly will wear out your drive.

Comment: Yes i would like to do it on disk.

Comment: If you do your research, you will find that such techniques are suspect on flash storage. http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/03/erasing_data_fr.html